# android lint - InvalidPackage errors when using apache odata-client-android

Tags: android, gradle, android-lint, olingo

I want to use the apache olingo odata library in an android project.
Since apache offers a specific build for android, i put this one as a dependency to my build.gradle file.

```
compile 'org.apache.olingo:odata-client-android:4.0.0'
```

When building the application, i run into multiple InvalidPackage lint errors:

As an example:

```
InvalidPackage: Package not included in Android
 odata-client-android-4.0.0.jar: Invalid package reference in library; 
 not included in Android: javax.activation. Referenced from
 com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.deser.DataHandlerJsonDeserializer.
```

There are also InvalidPackage errors for the `javax.xml.bind` package

As a Solution, it is suggested to add the following rule to build.gradle:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

So my questions are :

- Is it safe to add this rule? How can i be sure that this wont result in some runtime errors later.
- Since the artifact is dedidacted for android, shouldn´t such errors be fixed there? Or am i missing something else.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InvalidPackage` lint check flags packages that are not included by default on Android. If you're certain that the `javax.activation` package is not used on Android either because they provide a separate code path for using it, you can disable the check.

```
lintOptions {
  disable 'InvalidPackage',...
}
```

To get more information about the actual error you can use `lint --show InvalidPackage`

Comment: Is there an easy way to check if they offer a separate code path for the packages?

Comment: Sorry there is no easy way for me to tell. Are you using the jaxb annotations in your code?